# body goes inside SliverAppBar after using SliverOverlapAbsorber too

Tags: flutter, sliverappbar

flutter `NestedScrollView`:
body goes inside `SliverAppBar` of `headerSliverBuilder` after using `SliverOverlapAbsorber` too.

sample row 0 should not go inside tabs.

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: const HomePage(),
    ),
  );
}
```

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 4,
      child: Scaffold(
        body: NestedScrollView(
          physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
          headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
            return [
              SliverAppBar(
                title: Text("Hello1"),
                pinned: true,
              ),
              SliverList(
                delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                  [
                    Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      height: 240,
                      color: Colors.green,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: 8,
                        vertical: 24,
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              SliverOverlapAbsorber(
                handle:
                    NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(context),
                sliver: SliverAppBar(
                  title: Text("Another title"),
                  pinned: true,
                  bottom: TabBar(tabs: [
                    Tab(text: "Overview"),
                    Tab(text: "Overview1"),
                    Tab(text: "Overview2"),
                    Tab(text: "Overview3"),
                  ]),
                ),
              ),
            ];
          },
          body: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return CustomScrollView(
              slivers: [
                SliverOverlapInjector(
                    handle: NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(
                        context)),
                SliverList(
                  delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                    (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return ListTile(title: Text('Sample Row $index'));
                    },
                    childCount: 3,
                  ),
                )
              ],
            );
          }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

before scrolling (its ok)

[image]

after scrolling (sample row 0) shouldn't go inside tabs.

related issue:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/62194